# How to create a custom view for EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to have an EditText where the user will enter a password.
The problem is that it has to look a certain way:[image]

What I did is - I used EditText for each separate digit, however I don't think this is the right solution. Is there a way I can use only one EditText and make it look like that? Is there any other approach I can use?

Comment: spannableStrings might be what you are looking for

Comment: In my opinion, using different edit texts is the right way of doing it, as these are some pretty custom components, i dont know if this counts as an answer or not though :)